# Bash script error with sed command, integer expression expected

Tags: bash, sed, integer, expression

I can't figure out how to fix this error on my if statement ": integer expression expected0: [: 4". I have seem and read many similar questions on here, but none seem to fix this script!

I have the command enclosed in backticks:

```
today=`wget -q -O- "$URL" | sed -n "/$dateToday/ {n;n;n;n;p;q;}" | sed 's/<\/\?[^>]\+>//g; s/&deg\;//g; ' | tr -d ' ' `
```

I have tried using $() instead of backticks.

The printf works fine but I assume when it gets to the comparison operators it thinks its a string.

If I use "/bin/sh" there is no terminal error message, but it does not fix the issue as I need this for a cron job and the above error is then printed in the email body.

Full script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to send weather warnings via email when there is a risk of freezing

URL='http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/tormarton/gl9-1/daily-weather-forecast/708507'

dateToday=`date +"%b %-d"`      # gets Date in 'Mmm d' format
# Get todays temperature
today=`wget -q -O- "$URL" | sed -n "/$dateToday/ {n;n;n;n;p;q;}" | sed 's/<\/\?[^>]\+>//g; s/&deg\;//g; ' | tr -d ' ' `

# if temperatures <= to the warning temperature send email alert
if [ "$today" -le 10 ] ; then
     printf "Current temperature: $today\n" | mail -s "Weather warning forecast - Take precautions" address@mydomain.com
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this whitespace trimming:

```
today=`wget -q -O- "$URL" | sed -n "/$dateToday/ {n;n;n;n;p;q;}" | sed 's/<\/\?[^>]\+>//g; s/&deg\;//g; ' | tr -d '[:space:]'`
```

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to send weather warnings via email when there is a risk of freezing

URL='http://www.accuweather.com/en/gb/tormarton/gl9-1/daily-weather-forecast/708507'

dateToday=`date +"%b %-d"`      # gets Date in 'Mmm d' format
# Get todays temperature
today=`wget -q -O- "$URL" | sed -n "/$dateToday/ {n;n;n;n;p;q;}" | sed 's/<\/\?[^>]\+>//g; s/&deg\;//g; ' | tr -d '[:space:]'`

# if temperatures <= to the warning temperature send email alert
if [ "$today" -le 10 ] ; then
     printf "Current temperature: $today\n" | mail -s "Weather warning forecast - Take precautions" address@mydomain.com
fi
```

Comment: Well I never would of figured that out! Works thanks!